# Catching a keyboard hit is not reliable / Python

Tags: python, keyboard, keypress, msvcrt

The background is to design a program, which is running in an endless loop, to read live data from somewhere. I want this program to be controlled by interactions through keyboard (without 'Enter'). For this purpose I came across the following snippet.

```
import msvcrt

def keypress():
    try:
     if msvcrt.kbhit(): #Keyboard hit?
        key = msvcrt.getch().decode("utf-8").lower()    
        return key
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
     pass

while not False:
    print('rainy rainy rain rain')
    if keypress() == "e": #e: exit
        exit()
    if keypress() == "w": # w: wait
        waiting = True
        while waiting == True:
            print("waiting waiting waiting")
            if keypress() == "w":
                waiting = False
```

I know its frivolous to call a new endless loop just for waiting, but the crazy thing is the hit of "e" seems to be more often succesful than the hit of the "w". But in every case some few hits aren't even registered by no means at all.  -> Is there way this issue can be solved? Windows as well is able to catch every keyboard hit!

Answer (score 0):

```
while not False:
 print('rainy rainy rain rain')
 key = keypress()
 if key == "e": #e: exit
    exit()
 if key == "w": # w: wait
    waiting = True
    while waiting == True:
        print("waiting waiting waiting")
        if keypress() == "w":
            waiting = False
```

...this little change, solved the problem. I think calling the keypress() [and therefore also the msvcrt.getch() function] takes 'a lot' of time what prevents another keyboard hit from beeing recognized. But why? Shouldn't the hit of key beeing buffered!? And therefore the elapsed time shouldn't matter!?

Comment: First of all , I will suggest you to fix your code indentation.